# Is there a quick way to change settings on Android?

Tags: settings

Sometimes I need to quickly change a couple of settings, which are located deep enough (3 or more levels) in the settings menu. Is there a way to do this without actually opening the settings or writing my own app (which I could probably do, but why doing something that could be done more easily, right?) to do so?

I have thought about: maybe there is something like pinning certain settings to homescreen or something like *.bat* files on Windows? Or maybe there are certain apps where it is possible to quickly change settings from a list or even create some settings presets?

Comment: There are apps on Play Store that can help create shortcuts. Search for "settings shortcuts" or settings app etc

Comment: @beeshyams Most of the apps just open certain categories in settings. Can't find anything that actually helps changing settings quicker. Only found [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.simonesestito.ntiles) in some link on Stack Overflow. Wanted a shortcut for mono audio to start with - it requires root (weird, as long as I can change it manually). It seems like I'd better stick with manual changing for now, less time consuming than trying to tweak something to work.

Comment: Not all settings are accessible through commandline without root access. If yours are, or if your device is rooted, create a shell script and run it using Termux widget.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I will definitely give it a try, thanks for the idea

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut